# How to make Unrealizable characters in URL?

Tags: url

Im just wondering
How to make an URL to ignore loading some characters in it
like this :

```
http://example.com?test=test
"test=test"
```

the page will be normally loaded but `test=test` will not because its not realized on the webpage
how to do the same at the starter of the URL?

Comment: By starter of the URL are you referring to the host? If so then the host can not be changed unless that specific domain only uses a [wildcard dns record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) otherwise your changes will likely have side effects (most likely a redirection). ex. `http://test.example.com`

Comment: What server / host are you using?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this assumes you are running apache as your webserver

You need to change your httpd.conf and add a wildcard default server name.

see http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum92/3844.htm

Comment: my question was is it possible to start an url with like : http://(IGNORE).example.com.. i want the page to be loaded normally and at the same time this (IGNORE) subdomain being opened